# How to redirect while prompt is still active?

Tags: javascript, redirect, prompt

So say I have the following code:

```
window.prompt('Redirecting');
location.href = '/';
```

(I know this isn't useful code, but wait one sec) I can't figure out how to make it so that prompt doesn't 'freeze' the whole browser so that the redirect is forced to happen. So that in essence what I want is the prompt to come up and immediately for the page to redirect. (without user pressing anything)

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to have a timer on prompt to stop it after a while and/or to stop it from some other method. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have a timer to close a prompt, alert, confirm, etc.

If you want to do something like that you are going to have to build something using layers in JavaScript. Look at libraries like [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message), [YUI's](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/dialog/), dojos, or any other library out there.

Answer (score 0):

How alert, prompt, etc behave is up to the browser. Mostly, they are fully modal, so they block all input.
I'd suggest a framework such as FancyBox to show a popup that isn't modal and isn't under the browser's control.