# How do I cancel a javascript dialogue?

Tags: javascript, timer, dialog, timeout, block

I want to kick a user from a page if there is no activity for some time.

The prompt blocks the timer (so the page will be displayed until the promt is handled).

How do I cancel the prompt (or get around it, so the timer kicks the user if no entry in prompt box)?

---

```
var timeoutTimer = null;
var kickoutTimer = null;

timeoutTimer = setTimeout(function(){timeoutInfo()},10000);

function timeoutInfo()
{
    kickoutTimer = setTimeout(function(){kickout()},10000);

    var kickresponse = prompt('you will be kicked out soon - stop it? enter YES','');
    if( kickresponse == 'YES')
    {
        clearTimeout(kickoutTimer);
        alert('stopped');
    }
    else
    {
        kickout();
    }
}

function kickout()
{
    document.location='kickedout.html';
}
```

Comment: You can't programmatically close native JS Prompt window, you need to implement your own.

Comment: See [stackoverflow - How to redirect while prompt is still active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690438/how-to-redirect-while-prompt-is-still-active)

Comment: You can write your own prompt, or using jquery ui dialog for that.

Answer (score 0):

`windows.prompt()` and `windows.alert()` blocks UI and Javascript execution.

You have to use Javascript frameworks (AngularUI/jQuery UI/jQuery + Bootstrap/...) to show the dialog in HTML and have custom Javascript functions to handle the timeout.